# Populate the domain model from data layer, or query database direct?

Tags: database, hibernate, orm, architecture, domain-driven-design

Say I have a domain model where 3 objects interact, *Reservation*, *Vehicle* and *Fleet*.  The Fleet has many Vehicles, and each Vehicle can have many Reservations. e.g.

```
Fleet -1--*- Vehicle -1--*- Reservation
```

If I want *Fleet* to have a method *getMostPopularVehicle()*, I could have it iterate each Vehicle and count the number of Reservations.

If I then want to introduce an ORM for persistence, should I **(1)** have getMostPopularVehicle() call a data layer method to populate the Fleet, Vehicles and Reservations before iterating it as before?  Or should I **(2)** now just query the database directly to get the most popular vehicle in the data layer method?

My thinking is that (1) is correct, but a database query can be so efficient. Perhaps I am approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Are Fleet, Vehicle and Reservation all distinct aggregates?

Comment: No, if they were, I'd likely just represent them as transaction scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid. It depends on what you want to achieve; if you can get performance by issueing a (HQL or JPQL or whatever your ORM supports) query, which uses your domain model as well, it is quite legal to do this.

Comment: Uwe, many thanks.  Is one problem with (2) that I would need to change the getMostPopularVehicle() method, whereas with (1) I wouldn't?  Perhaps that is the tradeoff, direct query the database - faster, but affects the domain model?  Will upvote your answer once I get enough points to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If these statistics were expected to be readily available I'd probably go for one of 2 other options that would avoid executing a potentially heavy duty query as often (if at all):

3. Retrieve the data by querying the database directly (avoiding the domain model) using [CQRS](http://udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/).  The returned view models can be cached to avoid subsequent users causing the query to execute again.
4. Create a separate reporting database.  Key the values on fleet id and vehicle id and maybe increment the value by 5 for every reservation and then decrement EVERY value by 1 once a week, never going any lower than 0.  This way, you can keep fairly representative rolling statistics, whilst being able to quickly query the table and find the highest value row for a given fleet.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  Both 3 and 4 as you describe are really interesting.  4 is something I have never come across or considered before - great to learn of it.  One issue I see with 3, is what if getMostPopularVehicle() needs to be consumed from elsewhere in the model, i.e. in order to make a decision?

Comment: The approach of using a separate reporting database is a good one and isn't mentioned much because the world is still quite a heavy user of relational databases.  Separate reporting databases work specifically well if you're using a document database like MongoDB and approaches like DDD with Domain Events.

Comment: Adrian, the separate reporting database is definitely something i'm going to investigate - thanks again.  The Domain Events thing I'm thinking about.  I am unsure a command-aggregate-event-eventual consistency view of the world which I think it presupposes for many (may be wrong about that) is appropriate for my applications.  Thanks for pushing the way I think.

Comment: There is no disctinction between CQRS and a seperate reporting database if CQRS is properly implemented...